# How to change Android to show date based on Hijri Calendar?

Tags: android, root, android-calendar, hijri, persian-calendar

I need to change the Android phone to display Hijri date.  I am using Android 10 and have root access.

I modified the "framework-res.apk" file in sys folder and gave Persian values ​​to the Gregorian months, but converting the calendar to Persian is something beyond this.  I need a piece of code that converts the date before displaying it. I know the code but I don't know how to set and where to apply the code.

Probably, this issue will have the same answer for Iranian, Jalali, Lunar, Chinese and other calendars.

There is a limitation:
the actual value of the date should not be saved in Hijri, but it should be calculated only for display on the lock screen and notification bar.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.